# Use non-georeferenced raster with reference grid in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I have on one side a set of images in raster, which are not having any spatial reference, and on the other side a grid with spatial references. Each image supposedly fit perfectly in a cell of the grid. I would like, without hazardous manual georeferencing, to use the grid in order to give the rasters spatial references according to the grid references.

Any idea on how I could achieve this ?

Comment: You want some automatic georeferentiation, which is possible only raster to raster and not raster to vector, as far as I know. If you have the grid then you will need only 4 points per raster, which is not that much(assuming your set of images does not contain a couple of hundreds rasters). If your rasters do overlap you could try "automate->photomerge" from Photoshop and georeference 1 big raster.

Comment: There is also a georeferencing tool within QGIS. And you can also manually add a SRID to your image maybe? If you know their bounding boxes it would be great. Also, check out 'world files' on the Internet for your image format.